# Parsing text file with Java Streams API

Tags: java, parsing, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to parse a text file (`file1.txt`)

```
# ATown
# m
2        // this is var m
# Polynomials A
0 0 0 0 0        // the number of polynomials per section is m^2
0.20833 0 0 0 0  // the polynomials are always of degree 4
0 0.0333 -0.001388 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
# Polynomials B
0 0 0 0 0
0 0.048 -0.002 0 0
0.1428 0 0 0 0
0.0588 0 0 0 0
```

The spaces separated numbers represent polynomials and should be split at the spaces and put into an array of ints which should go into their respective ArrayList.
I would like to put the `2` into an `int m` and Polynomials A into an ArrayList `List<double []> polyA` and `List<double []> polyB`.
And I would like to use the Streams API.

Comment: 0.20833 and the others are not int, but double

Comment: it's really confusing what you want to achieve... so `0 0 0 0 \n 0.20833 0 0 0 0` should generate an `ArrayList` of two elements, where each element is an array on ints, right? the next thing you want to do is *really* confusing, may be provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Streams are not designed to look back at previous elements, which you somehow need to determine whether the current line represents a number of either Polynomials A or B.

I suggest you use a regular for-loop.